# Ideal $+$ maximal regular ideal = whole ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, $A$ be an ideal of $R$, $\rho$ be a maximal regular right ideal of $R$, then if $A\not\subset\rho$ the maximality of $\rho$ forces $A+\rho=R$.

Above is in a proof of a theorem, but I can't see why it's true, can anyone explain?

(A right ideal $ρ$ of $R$ is said to be regular if there is an $a\in R$ such that $x-ax\in\rho$ for all $x\in R$.)

Comment: What definition of regular ideal is being used? (This term is [overloaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_ideal#Regular_element_ideals).)

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you for your comment. I have added the definition to the post.

Comment: If $x - ax \in \rho$ for every $x$ then $x - ax \in A + \rho$ for every $x$. So if $\rho$ is regular, so is $A + \rho$.

Comment: The thing Is that any right ideal containing a regular ideal is itself regular.  So whether you are talking about a maximal right ideal that is regular or a maximal-regular right ideal, it is the same thing, and it is also just a plain maximal right ideal.  Not all maximal right ideals have to be regular of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $A+\rho$ is a right ideal, since $\rho$ is maxiimal, $A+\rho=R$

Comment: What if $A+\rho$ is not regular?

Comment: show that it is regular.